# Bughunt in Calendar Function

Tags: php, navigation, calendar

I wrote a Calendar Script that worked pretty well until i wanted to add navigation for last/next month/year. When i called that function with printmonth($m,$y); it worked and showed current month, when i called printmonth($m+1,$y); it showed next month. Now that i added navigation to NOT call function manually it doesn't work, it shows december of current year. Always. It even tries to navigate to 13th month althogh i added if statements to check if it is the last month of the year or first month of the year. Please comment if you see something suspicious, i know its terrible structure and variable names are not pretty, but i'm doing my first steps in PHP.

Thanks for your time and feedback, here is my function:

```
function printmonth($month,$year) {

// abort if invalid values

if($month>=13) { die("No month >=13 please");   };
if(($year<=1970) || ($year>=3000)) {die("No year <=1970 or >=3000 please");};

// an array of names

$mnames = array(
    1 => "Januar",
    2 => "Februar",
    3 => "März",
    4 => "April",
    5 => "Mai",
    6 => "Juni",
    7 => "Juli",
    8 => "August",
    9 => "September",
    10 => "Oktober",
    11 => "November",
    12 => "Dezember"
);    

// more vars

$month     = intval($month);
$year      = intval($year);    
$thisday   = intval(date('j'));
$thismonth = intval(date('m'));
$thisyear  = intval(date('Y'));

$weekday        = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,"01",$year));
$lastdayofmonth = date('t', mktime(0,0,0,$month,2,$year));
$oneless        = $weekday-1;

/* calculate end of last month */

$lastdayoflastmonth = date('t', mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,2,$year));
$pp=$lastdayoflastmonth-$oneless+1;

$seven = 0+$weekday;

// next year/month... problem must be somewhere in this section

$prevyear = $year-1;
$nextyear = $year+1;
if ($month=1)  { $prevmonth=12;         $nextmonth=$month+1; };
if ($month=12) { $prevmonth=$month-1;   $nextmonth=1;  };
if (($month>=2) || ($month<=11)) {$prevmonth=$month-1; $nextmonth=$month+1;};

// print table head and navigation and day names

echo('<table class="cal">'."\n");

echo('<tr class="headnav">'."\n");
echo('    <td class="headtd"><a href="?y='.$prevyear.'&m='.$month.'">|<</a></td>'."\n");
echo('    <td class="headtd"><a href="?y='.$year.'&m='.$prevmonth.'">&lt;</a></td>'."\n");
echo('    <td class="headtd" colspan="3">'.$mnames[$month].' '.$year.'</td>'."\n");
echo('    <td class="headtd"><a href="?y='.$year.'&m='.$nextmonth.'">&gt;</a></td>'."\n");
echo('    <td class="headtd"><a href="?y='.$nextyear.'&m='.$month.'">>|</a></td>'."\n");
echo('</tr>'."\n");

echo('<tr class="head">'."\n");
echo('   <td class="headtd">Mo</td>'."\n");
echo('   <td class="headtd">Di</td>'."\n");
echo('   <td class="headtd">Mi</td>'."\n");
echo('   <td class="headtd">Do</td>'."\n");
echo('   <td class="headtd">Fr</td>'."\n");
echo('   <td class="headtd">Sa</td>'."\n");
echo('   <td class="headtd">So</td>'."\n");
echo('</tr>'."\n");

echo(' <tr>'."\n");

//print end of last month

for ($l=1;$l<=$oneless;$l++) { 
    echo('<td class="placebegin">'.$pp.'</td>'."\n");
    $pp++;
};

// print each day until last day of month

for ($x=1;$x<=$lastdayofmonth;$x++) 
    { 
        if (($x==$thisday) && ($thismonth==$month) && ($thisyear==$year))
            {$bold = 1;} 
                else {$bold = 0;};

        if ($seven<=7) { 
            if ($bold = 1) 
                {      echo('<td class="today"><a href="tage.php?d='.$x.'&m='.$month.'&y='.$year.'" class="tag">'.$x.'</a></td>'."\n"); } 
                else { echo('<td class="row">  <a href="tage.php?d='.$x.'&m='.$month.'&y='.$year.'" class="tag">'.$x.'</a></td>'."\n");};

            $seven++; 

      } else { 
          echo('</tr><tr>'); 
          $seven = 1; 
          $x--; 
      };

    };

// print numbers until row is complete    

$p = 1;
for ($e=$seven;$e<=7;$e++) { echo('<td class="placebegin">'.$p.'</td>'); $p++; };


// complete table
echo ('   </tr> ');
echo (' </table>');

//done

}; 

//function ends here, the call and some vars:


if (isset($_GET['y']) && (!empty($_GET['y']))) 
{
$y=intval($_GET['y']);
} 
    else 
        {
        $y = intval(date('Y'));
        };

if (isset($_GET['m']) && (!empty($_GET['m']))) 
{
$m=intval($_GET['m']);
} 
    else 
        {
        $m = intval(date('n'));
        };

// call function

printmonth($m, $y);
```

Comment: Not immediately an answer, but why do you perform `intval` **after** you checked bounds?

Comment: What happens if you replace all `if($month=1)` (and other values) by `if($month == 1)`?

Comment: Ok, i had an accidental assignment in an if. There should be == instad of =, thanks, if found it.

Comment: And i will perform    intval before those checks, thanks.

Comment: I've also added some errors, my php engine detected... Warnings don't have to be resolved, but sometimes it's better to take a look at them, simple to avoid that your code is not backward compatible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you use

```
if($month == 1)//condition
```

instead of

```
if($month = 1)//assignment
```

as well as the second `if`.

The third if must use an `&&` instead of `||`, thus replace

```
if (($month>=2) || ($month<=11))
```

by

```
if (($month>=2) && ($month<=11))
```

An assignment succeeds and (if I recall correctly if the variable you assign is set after the operation). Thus `$month = 1` succeeds. As as a result, the `$prevmonth` is set to `12`, thus december...

When I run your function myself, it works... Although one gets a lot of warnings...

> **Warning**:  date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead on line **29**
>
> **Warning**:  date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead on line **30**
>
> **Warning**:  date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead on line **31**
>
> **Warning**:  mktime() [function.mktime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to
>   use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set()
>   function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still
>   getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone
>   identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead
>   on line **33**
>
> **Warning**:  date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead on line **33**
>
> **Warning**:  mktime() [function.mktime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to
>   use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set()
>   function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still
>   getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone
>   identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead
>   on line **34**
>
> **Warning**:  date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead on line **34**
>
> **Warning**:  mktime() [function.mktime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to
>   use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set()
>   function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still
>   getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone
>   identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead
>   on line **39**
>
> **Warning**:  date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use
>   the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
>   In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead on line **39**

Comment: This is intresting, i don't get any warnings. I will add date_default_timezone_set(Europe/Berlin);

Comment: You need to set the warning level (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Of course only report warnings  during development. Otherwise hackers can use this info to know how your site works...

Comment: error_reporting(-1); is what i use. No warnings if i remove timezone line.

Comment: There is still a problem with the navigation of months, if its 12(december), it wants to navigate to 13th month. If its 1(january) it navigates to current month. Those if's dont work for 1st and 12th month.

Comment: @cli: did you replace the second `if` as well?

Comment: @cli: found it: the third if must be replaced with and `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: Yes, thats it. Now i need to expand this to add one year if it's the skip from december to jan, and substract one from year if it's the skip from jan to dec. I'll do it later, thanks for your help so far :)